# findByIdAndUpdate adding another document to the database rather than updating

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, mongoose, crud

I am using MEAN stack for patient CRUD operations. The update does not seem to be working properly. It adds another document to the database with the updated info but with a null id and leaves the old document that is supposed to be updated as is.
below is the code I wrote in the service for update patient

```
editPatient(id:string,patient: Patient){
    const headers = { 'content-type': 'application/json'}  
    const body=patient;
    console.log(body)
     
    let url=environment.PATIENT_BASE_URL+environment.PATIENT.UPDATE_PATIENT + "?userId=" +id;
    return this.httpClient.put(url, body);

  }
```

Those are the contents of the environment file

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    BASE_URL:'http://localhost:3000',
    PATIENT_BASE_URL:'http://localhost:3000/patients/',
    PATIENT:{
        
        GET_ALL_PATIENTS: 'list',
        GET_PATIENT: 'view',
        UPDATE_PATIENT: 'update',
        DELETE_PATIENT: 'delete',
        SEARCH_PATIENT: 'search',
        ADD_PATIENT: 'add',
    
    
    
    }
  };
```

This is the code in patients.js

```
router.put('/update', function(req, res, next) {

  const userId = req.body.userId;

  let firstnameVal = req.body.firstName;
let lastnameVal = req.body.lastName;
let usernameVal = req.body.username;
let emailVal = req.body.email;
let birthDateVal = req.body.birthDate;
let genderVal = req.body.gender;



let patientObj = {

  firstName: firstnameVal,
  lastName: lastnameVal,
  username: usernameVal,
  email: emailVal,
  birthDate : birthDateVal,
  gender: genderVal

};

  // patientsModel.update({'gender':'female'}, )
  patientsModel.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, patientObj,{upsert: true, new: true} ,function(err, patientResponse){
    if(err){
      res.send({status:500, message: 'Unable to update the patient'});
     }
   
     else{

       res.send({status:200, message: 'User updated successfully'  ,results: patientResponse});
     }

    });


});
```

Comment: What is the datatype of the _id in the schema?

Comment: the id is automatically generated and is not specified in the schema

Comment: What does the `userId` look like at that point? Are you able to use `findById` to retrieve the patient using that value?

Comment: PUT /patients/update?userId=63b310df2b36d95e156a237d

Comment: 63b310df2b36d95e156a237d is the id generated by the database

Comment: it works perfectly fine with ```findById```

Answer (score 0):

Because you used this option

```
upsert: true
```

If item with id not found it creates a new document

you can read [the docs here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html#upsert)

> Using the upsert option, you can use findOneAndUpdate() as a
> find-and-upsert operation. An upsert behaves like a normal
> findOneAndUpdate() if it finds a document that matches filter. But, if
> no document matches filter, MongoDB will insert one by combining
> filter and update as shown below.

Comment: it now inserts a new document with a different (non-null) id and keeps the old document. is there anyway by which the new document can replace the old document?

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to [findByIdAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-findByIdAndUpdate) is an update object.  If it does not contain any update operators, it is treated as a replacement document.

If your intent is to replace the entire document so the only fields it contains are the ones provided in this function, add the `_id` to the object:

```
let patientObj = {
  _id: new  mongoose.types.ObjectId(userId),
  firstName: firstnameVal,
 ...
```

If the intent is to modify the provided fields but leave any others fields alone, use the [$set](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) update operator like

```
patientsModel.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, {"$set": patientObj}, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code - as others have said:

1. the use of `upsert: true` is suspicious - I can't imagine when you'd want to upsert this, and
2. the lack of `$set` is also unusual unless the `patientObj` represents the entire document you wish to set

both these items are causing you issues, but I suspect your main problem is actually that your ID doesn't match anything.

You mention an auto-generated ID. Mongo uses an `ObjectId` (though mongoose perhaps does not) - depending on how you serialise this value, the string representation of it would probably look like this: `63b310df2b36d95e156a237d` - however when you query for that value (as you do with `userId`) - it will return no matches, since you need to convert it to an object ID:

```
userId = new  mongoose.types.ObjectId(req.body.userId)
```

You should also fix items 1 and 2 above.